# How does heroku works with git?

Tags: git, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I just started to learn about heroku, I made deploy but I didn't understand it very well.

I have my git repository with it all my project, I did `$ heroku create` and follow the [heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#deploy-your-application-to-heroku)

Then I noticed that I can update my app server with

```
$ git push heroku master
```

and I can also make pull to my bitbucket repository normally with

```
$ git pull
```

So, can I use my bitbucket repository for develop without troubles and just make `$ git push heroku master` to actualizate the server? how does it work?

Besides, should I have a different git repository(maybe another folder) to make deploy or use the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two separate remotes, one for pushing to your local development changes to (like on GitHub or Bitbucket), and the other remote for deploying to production (in this case, Heroku).

You can push from your local clone (if you want), you don't necessarily need to keep a separate local Git repo for this purpose.